# How to calculate necessary gain to compensate a loss in a financial transaction?

Tags: returns

(Feel free to suggest the correct Stackexchange community - or otherwise - if this is not the correct one)

When trading financial markets, a gain of `x`%, won't recover a loss of `x`% (same applies to any gain-loss scenario, in any market, I assume)

e.g. I start with 100, I lose 2% (98% or original capital), I gain 2%. I'm still in loss (99.96% of original capital)

**Is there a formula to calculate the necessary % gain of a single transaction over `k` loss of x% gain after y losses of x%**? (if the formula is generalized to `z` gains of x% and `k` losses of x% is preferable - x% is fixed)

Comment: I don't quite understand the last paragraph; is your loss/gain $x$ fixed? So, you suppose that we occur $y$ losses and then $k$ gains of $x$. So the losses/gains are in exactly that order and not mixed und each of them is $x%$? Last, you ask on the necessary percentage gain of a *single* transaction needed, to recover all losses, right?

Comment: loss/gain % fixed and = to x% (of the current balance). My goal is how to find an expectancy model where by winning and losing x% z and k times respectively, I will still be having a gain higher than the initial capital. The formula would allow me to calculate how many wins I need to cover one loss. Another alternative is indeed what you say, the necessary % to recover the losses in 1 transaction, after k losses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let x represent the percent change-e.g. 2%, let k represent the number of decreases, and z the number of increases. Something like this? We want to find z such that:

$\left(1-x\right)^k\left(1+x\right)^z=1$

Rearrange,

$\left(1+x\right)^z=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^k}$

And take log:

$z \ln \left(1+x\right)=-k \ln \left(1-x\right)$

and solve for z:

$z =-k \frac{\ln \left(1-x\right)}{\ln \left(1+x\right)}$

Or you want z to represent the percent increase such that:

$\left(1-x\right)^k\left(1+z\right)^k=1$

$z=\frac{1}{1-x}-1=\frac{x}{1-x}$

Comment: could you elaborate the answer by specifying what k, z and x represent? for the sake of clarity (even though I assume you've just used the same variables as in the question)

Comment: Added more explanation, hope it is clearer now.

Comment: much clearer. thanks. but where is the `k` in the second formula, if based on what  I read the second formula is the `% increase` necessary after `k` decreases of `x`% (which is in fact what'd fully give a complete answer)

Comment: When you take the k-th root of both sides , the k disappear, thanks to the right hand side being equal to 1.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common question type on the GMAT.

Suppose you lose x% of your initial funds, $V_0$, so you now have $V_0(1-x/100)$. What y% return on the new funds do you need to return to your initial funds?

Stated this way, we express our problem as:

$V_0(1-x/100)(1+y/100)=V_0 $,  or
$(1-x/100)(1+y/100)=1$

Solving for y, we have:

$y= \frac{100}{1-x/100}-100$, or

$y=\frac{x/100}{1-x/100}$

Comment: this would cover the answer for "how much gain for one loss". is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Or vice versa